# How to prompt user for additional info if I can't issue a certain claim?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I have a scenario when I want add claims in `GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)` in `ProfileService`. These claims are required for a **particular client** only, not all of them. However the user haven't filled required info beforehand, let's say it's phone number.

What should I do at this moment? What is best practice? Should I somehow fail issuing token in `GetProfileDataAsync` and redirect a user to page where the user is being asked for missing phone number? But in order to associate that new phone number with his account first I need to authenticate the user so I need to issue the token anyway and then somehow reissue it after filling missing info.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I would check for this in the IdentityServer /Account page logic, so when the user is authenticated, you also check for missing claims before you call PasswordSignInAsync to sign in the user IdentityServer.

Ie, before this:

```
  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberLogin, lockoutOnFailure: true);
```